# Random no start issue...95 buick lesabre limited edition (vin type L)

Tags: starting, starter, buick, lesabre

So i drive a 1995 buick lesabre limited edition V6 3.8ltr which is relatively in good shape and only has 197,000km. Recently I:

- Replaced the water pump
- Fixed an oil leak coming from the sleeve around the drain plug
- Changed the oil filter and did oil change at the same time.
- Put in some oil system cleaner and treatment stuff; ran it through before doing oil change. Then when adding new oil I put this engine stop leak Stuff and oil  conditioner maintenance stuff you use after the cleaner Stuff.
- I cleaned as much of the oil off as I could from undercarriage, engine area and tires . (started no problem after pressure washing it all too.)
- I replaced the spark plugs as well except I could only replace 3 out of the 6 when I did it, because the last package I grabbed was the wrong one. Oops. So I just did the front 3 (2 days ago). I still have to go to store for the other package.
- I've recently (like within 2 weeks) replaced the battery cables, the connector ends, the terminals, battery, and starter cable connector ends.

Yesterday I had the car on accessory for 5 hours with the stereo just pounding (not exaggerating time frame either!!), never started it at all during that time and it started without hesitation when I went to leave.

So today I get in drive it starts runs no issues. Go to Timmies, turn it off come out starts no problem again. Go park in the shade somewhere and had car on accessory to listen to music. Listen to 2 or 3 songs and zoned out on phone not picking the next song to play. 20 mins to half hour later I go to start car and it won't start. The cluster lights all come on but there's nothing when I try to start it. No clicking doesn't even try to crank or turn over. I ask someone for a boost. Does EXACT SAME THING. what the heck????

Never had issues starting it before ... I know my alternator is fine as I just tested it last week. Shouldn't be the starter as they didn't randomly just go ... to nth knowledge you'd have intermittent no starts but starts on jump starts and then defiant when not fixed it'll eventually stop. Which isn't this case. But I'm kinda stumped. Someone please help! Also I thought the starter could be locked but I'm not on a hill and did the trucks to unlock it and still nothing.

Comment: Have you re-checked the starter cable ends? That sounds like a possibility...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Bad starter motor....